# Enclosing part of a string in `<i>` tag

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a string like:

```
<a href="x.com">x.com</a>
```

..in which I want to replace the text of the tag so it is wrapped in a `<i>` tag:

```
<a href="x.com"><i>x.com</i></a>
```

Using regex `>.*<`, I get a match for `>x.com<` but I really just want the exact text so I can `gsub` it:

```
'<a href="x.com">x.com</a>'.gsub(<what here?>,<what here?>)
```

How do I do this?

**UPDATE**

**Ps.** This is in Rails 3.0.3 on Ruby 1.8.7 p330

Comment: Don't ever try to "parse" HTML with regular expressions. That is not going to work. Use an actual parser like nokogiri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would very strongly recommend not editing HTML like this, but this should do what you want:

```
'<a href="x.com">x.com</a>'.gsub(/>(.*?)</, '><i>\1</i><')
```

Comment: How to avoid having to include `>` and `<` in the replacement text `><i>\1</i><` ?

Comment: See sawa's answer, which utilizes lookahead and lookbehind assertions to only match the target text.  Alternatively you could also put the `>` and `<` inside of parentheses and use `\1<i>\2</i>\3` as the replacement text, but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 2):

[Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) is a great tool for parsing HTML and XML in Ruby. Using it frees you from dealing with all sorts of HTML inconsistencies due to malformed markup, or changing structure.

This would wrap the contents of all `<a>` tags throughout a HTML document:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<a href="x.com">x.com</a>'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html)

doc.search('a').each do |_node|  
  _node.inner_html = "<i>#{_node.content}</i>"
end

puts doc

# >> <a href="x.com"><i>x.com</i></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use (?<=pattern) which specifies the preceding context and (?=pattern) which specifies the following context.

```
'<a href="x.com">x.com</a>'.gsub(/(?<=\>).*?(?=\<)/, '<i>\0</i>')
```

Comment: I get an error: `undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<=\>).*?(?=\<)/`. (I'm using Ruby 1.8.7, if that matters?)

Comment: Yes. Its only available in ruby1.9. Sorry about that. But you can make it work on ruby1.8.7 if you install oniguruma. (Please don't ask me how to. Some other person may be able to help you with that.)

Comment: It appears that Ruby does not support lookbehind.  Reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @Andrew Ruby1.9 uses oniguruma as the regexp engine, and it does have lookbehind.

Comment: Installing oniguruma under ruby1.8 seems easier than I thought. Try this link: [link](http://oniguruma.rubyforge.org/)

Answer (score 1):

How about adding parenthesis using `>(.*)<` not `>.*<` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know Ruby very well, but maybe it has an HTML parsing library that can do this more reliably than regexes?

[Obligatory link re parsing HTML with regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I only need this for a very simple case and would rather not go too far with HTML parsing n all .. thanks for that link, though.

Comment: @Zabba: sure, for simple stuff like this it’s probably easier busting out a regex.

Comment: "it’s probably easier busting out a regex". Until the HTML changes. Or you need to process HTML from two different sources.

Comment: @the Tin Man: well, maybe. But surely all approaches need reworking when the HTML changes? I’m not quite clear what difference it makes if you’re processing HTML from two different sources either?

Comment: A parser isolates you from HTML changes in many ways that Regex can't, unless you have an extremely complicated pattern. I've written a lot of regex and a lot of HTML scrapers and spiders, into the hundreds, and learned some hard lessons. HTML isn't regex friendly so for anything beyond a trivial use a parser simplifies the code and maintenance.